# My code work only on line by line executing

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filePath);

document.Info.Author = "";
document.Info.Title = "";
document.Info.Creator = "";

document.Close();
document.Dispose();

document.Save(filePath);
```

When I execute it line by line in Debug mode it works perfect. But, when I run it without line by line executing I get an error 'the filePath is used by another process' on Save operation.

What is the problem?

Comment: As the error suggests, there is some other process using the file you are trying to open. When running it line by line you are giving that other process enough time to release the resources and make the file available again. This could mean that you are either: a) using the file through some othe application, or b) you are not properly releasing the handles to that file from your current application.

Comment: You may need to use using statement when opening the file as you are dealing with I/O operation.
Example: [link](https://www.xspdf.com/guide/pdf-combine/)

Comment: `document.Dispose();` and then `document.Save(filePath);` ????  Why would you dispose something before saving?

Comment: How can you Save() after Dispose() ??

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to this;

```
using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filePath))
{
    document.Info.Author = "";
    document.Info.Title = "";
    document.Info.Creator = "";

    document.Save(filePath);
    document.Close();
}
```

As Jeroen van Langen pointed out in the comment, you cannot close and dispose and then save. The using statement takes care of dispose for you.

**Edit;**

Correction regarding close.

Comment: `using` will take care of `Dispose()` for you, but it won't necessarily take care of `Close()` for you, unless internally the implementation of `Dispose()` calls `Close()`. Under the hood, `using` is just a `try/finally` where `finally` calls `obj.Dispose()`.

Comment: You're right, "normally" documents and files are closed automatically by their dispose method, but that does not seem to be the case with `PdfDocument`.

Comment: It's the same problem :((

Comment: Sorry! When correcting my answer I made the same mistake you did - I put the close method before save when it should be the other way around! :) Try again with the new version!

Comment: No way, same error: 'The process cannot access the file 'filepath' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: Ensure that all processes that ran previously are terminated. This will not work otherwise.

Comment: I may be way off here, but try a restart :) You may have processes using your file path remaining from previous debug sessions.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was the antivirus. When I turned it off, it all work perfect. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `using` statement. 
`using` is used for doing heavy stuff, when `using` statement finish it's job the Dispose is called, The `using` statement ensures that Dispose is called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was the antivirus. When I turned it off, it all work perfect. Thanks to all of you